# How turn off autofocus with CameraBridgeViewBase opencv4android

Tags: opencv, autofocus

I'm developing an app for Android 4.2.2, and I want to turn off the autofocus. There is a way to do it if I'm using CameraBridgeViewBase?

The version of the opencv library is 2.4.5. The specific device in which that I want the app to work fine is Samsung Galaxy s3.

Answer (score 0):

actually i can't present a working solution. But Moster posted a realy good solution for focus and flash [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/19796/android-use-autofocus-with-camerabridgeviewbase/#19813).

He created a class inherited from JavaCameraView and overload some initialization methods! I guess you just need to add a functionality for turning it off. Or you just fix it with type 3 (Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_FIXED).